# Wordpress Changing font

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog " www.freelancing4arab.com", I want to change the theme font, I edit the css but nothing changed, obviously my blog is in Arabic so I want to use a cool arabic font.

So what do you think ? what was the problem? why the changes didn't take place ?

And can I use a special font I mean a font that the user doesn't have on there machine but it's uploaded on my server - I know it's possible but I want to know how -

This is my website css file : http://freelancing4arab.com/wp-content/themes/WebColors/style.css

Comment: what have you changed and what font you want to use?

Comment: Have you done a Force Refresh (Ctrl+F5) to ensure you are not loading a cached version of your stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To use non web-font, please check out font-face: http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/
2. I am not sure what you'd changed in your css. But the font isnt changing is because:

   font-family: HelveticaNeue, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;

HelveticaNeue is not a web font. so if you dont have HelveticaNeue installed in your computer, you wont see text appear in that font.

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face { font-family: ArabicFont; src: url('ArabicFont.otf'); }
```